# Where does a web project store its references?

Tags: asp.net

We've added a reference to a web project, which we would now like to check in in TFS.
For a normal project, you would just check in the project file (.csproj). However, a web project does not have a project file.
Does anyone know in which file the references of a web project are stored, so we can check in only that file?

Comment: _However, a web project does not have a project file_. I hope you're not talking about `Visual Studio`.

Comment: Thanks @CodeCaster. That provided me with the answer!